# How can I make an extranet site for a customer portal without issuing licences to the customer

Tags: 2013, licensing, extranet

I am trying to set up a customer portal in Sharepoint 2013.  The goal is for the customer to come on the site and check the Order Status, Incident Report and to view Invoices.  I would like to do this without having to pay for extra licenses.  What is the easiest and if possible the cheapest way to do this?

Comment: You don't need CALs' for external users. I couldn't find the 2013 licensing page but this is the 2016: https://products.office.com/en-us/sharepoint/sharepoint-licensing-overview

Comment: @Bunzab add your comment as an answer it's a correct one, but note “External Users” means users that are neither your or your affiliates’ employees, nor your or your affiliates’ onsite contractors or onsite agents. for more details https://www.degdigital.com/insights/sharepoint-2013-licensing-for-dummies/

Comment: The "you don't need CALs" highly depends on the mode of authentication. If they're Active Directory users, you absolutely need Windows CALs (or a Windows External Connector). Of course, as stated, you don't need SharePoint CALs.

Answer (score 3):

I'm really hesitant to give licensing advice on anything MS related as it is a minefield of confusion. See @M.Quassas comment for more specific details as to what an external user is but I also found more specifics for 2013 [here](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/volume-licensing/2013/08/08/licensing-how-to-sharepoint-server-2013-licensing-changes/)

Please ensure you consult with your MS partner before making any decisions.

Comment: Agree to Bunzab. Ask your Licensing-Partner for help on this topic. If you ask 2 partners, you will get 5 answers. My tactic: Ask as lot of partners as you can and save the best answer for you ;-)